# Why is there "seccomp" events related to Google Chrome in syslog?

Tags: google-chrome, syslog

Was in my syslog today and noticed that the Google Chrome web browser is create TONS of events that look like this:

```
Dec  7 13:11:02 mycomp-sys76 kernel: [ 8371.604406] type=1701 audit(1354903862.279:314): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=8859 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=4 compat=0 ip=0x7f8ebb41b205 code=0x50000
Dec  7 13:11:02 mycomp-sys76 kernel: [ 8371.604408] type=1701 audit(1354903862.279:315): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=8859 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=4 compat=0 ip=0x7f8ebb41b205 code=0x50000
Dec  7 13:11:02 mycomp-sys76 kernel: [ 8371.604411] type=1701 audit(1354903862.279:316): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=8859 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=4 compat=0 ip=0x7f8ebb41b205 code=0x50000
Dec  7 13:11:02 mycomp-sys76 kernel: [ 8371.604413] type=1701 audit(1354903862.279:317): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=8859 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=4 compat=0 ip=0x7f8ebb41b205 code=0x50000
Dec  7 13:11:02 mycomp-sys76 kernel: [ 8371.810789] type=1701 audit(1354903862.487:318): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=8868 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=4 compat=0 ip=0x7f8ebb41b205 code=0x50000
```

Anybody know what these are and if they are a problem and how to make them go away (without just disabling kernel logging?)

Answer (score 4):

It's just the kernel logging audit events of [seccomp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp) from Chrome's sandbox.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp):

> seccomp (short for secure computing mode) is a simple sandboxing
>   mechanism for the Linux kernel. It was added in Linux kernel 2.6.12 in
>   March 8, 2005.
>
> It allows a process to make a one-way transition into a "secure" state
>   where it cannot make any system calls except exit(), sigreturn(),
>   read() and write() to already-open file descriptors. Should it attempt
>   any other system calls, the kernel will terminate the process with
>   SIGKILL.
>
> In this sense, it does not virtualize the system's resources but
>   isolates the process from them entirely.

---

> Google is exploring using seccomp for sandboxing its Chrome web
>   browser.
>
> As of Chrome version 20, seccomp is used to sandbox Adobe Flash
>   Player. As of Chrome version 23, seccomp is used to sandbox the
>   renderers.

See also:

- [Chrome 20 on Linux and Flash sandboxing](http://scarybeastsecurity.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/chrome-20-on-linux-and-flash-sandboxing.html)
- [Introducing Chrome's next-generation Linux sandbox](http://blog.cr0.org/2012/09/introducing-chromes-next-generation.html)
- [A safer playground for your Linux and Chrome OS renderers](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/11/a-safer-playground-for-your-linux-and.html)

Comment: That is very cool...so there are as many of these seccomp entries as there are chrome tabs/child processes, yes?  Any way to turn off these off?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to silence these messages, as they're being sent by kernel itself. Maybe [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/manual.html) has some filter capabilities.

Comment: you can filter them pretty easily, on my system I made a `/etc/rsyslog.d/30-seccomp.conf` file with the contents of `if $msg contains ' comm="chrom' then /var/log/chrome-seccomp.log
  2 & ~` make sure the & ~ is on the second line.