# How do I redirect Google Chrome Logs out of my kern.log

Tags: google-chrome, logging

I have hundreds of these log entries:

```
Feb 13 16:46:56 XXXX kernel: [42982.178922] type=1701 audit(1360799216.852:1514): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=5529 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=2 compat=0 ip=0x7f3060b476b0 code=0x50000
Feb 13 16:46:56 XXXX kernel: [42982.178943] type=1701 audit(1360799216.852:1515): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=5529 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=2 compat=0 ip=0x7f3060b476b0 code=0x50000
```

This behavior is explained here: [Why is there "seccomp" events related to Google Chrome in syslog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226578/why-is-there-seccomp-events-related-to-google-chrome-in-syslog).

How do I redirect them out of my `kern.log` file?

I plan to figure out this log later, but I have other projects that would be easier with a smaller `kern.log` file.

I have seen this: [How to enable logging for Google Chrome in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236425/how-to-enable-logging-for-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-12-04)

The file mentioned is not under my home folder.

Default install.  Edit:  Basic plug-ins.  Single profile. Checked the menu item and the only option `%U` (no `--debug` or anything like that)

about:

```
Google Chrome   24.0.1312.69 (Official Build 180721)
OS  Linux 
WebKit  537.17 (@140072)
JavaScript  V8 3.14.5.6
Flash   11.5.31.139
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/24.0.1312.69 Safari/537.17
```

Comment: In the accepted answer.  ~/.config/google-chrome or ~/.config/chrome has no .log file that I can find.  I was assuming this is default behavior and I thought it was a good trouble shooting step.  Should I remove the reference?

Comment: Okay, I checked syslog as well. No seccomp entry for me. What is your google-chrome version? Maybe you could add to your question information from typing `about:` in the address bar and hitting `enter`. I'm deleting my earlier comments before the system tries to push us into chat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to tweak your rsyslog configuration to process those messages differently. So for example you can create /etc/rsyslog.d/30-seccomp.conf:

```
if $msg contains 'comm="chrome" reason="seccomp"' then /var/log/chrome.log
& ~
```

Followed by:

```
initctl restart syslog
```

The rule states if the message contains the string then forward it to /var/log/chrome.log. The second line means that anything that matched the first line should be dropped.

If you just want to drop all these messages:

```
if $msg contains 'comm="chrome" reason="seccomp"' then ~
```

Answer (score 2):

If using an open source version of Chrome (like on Ubuntu the version installed with `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`) then redirecting the seccomp logging requires a slightly-different rsyslogd filter.

For reference Chromium syslog messages look like this:

```
Feb 23 17:33:16 XXX kernel: [507549.071917] type=1701 audit(1393194796.933:3999): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=21016 comm="chromium-browse" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=2 compat=0 ip=0x7f2b40940eb0 code=0x50001
```

And building on stsquad's answer, here is an `/etc/rsyslog.d/30-seccomp.conf` that's been generalized to work with both Google Chrome and open source Chromium:

```
if $msg contains ' reason="seccomp"' and $msg contains ' comm="chrom' \
  then -/var/log/chrome-seccomp.log
& ~
```

Answer (score 0):

How about scripting a grep hack?

```
grep -Ev 'chrome' /var/log/kern.log >> /var/log/smaller.kern.log
```